# What is the best way to create and manage global Procs and UDFs in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

Let's imagine that I have 2 separate Databases on the same instance of SQL Server.
DB1 is a Database relating to Trading and Position Keeping.
DB2 is a Database relating to market pricing variables.

Both databases have the concept of working with time/date objects and I have created some convenience UDFs. Lets further imagine I build some convenient math functions that I would like to be called from all databases. What is the best way of creating and organising them?

i.e. Should I create the UDFs and SPs in the Master Database? How should I group all my CustomDateTime UDFs, is it best to create something in the Schema so that I replace .dbo with .myDateTime or .myMath?

Suggestions appreciated as I do not like how I currently have placed most of my functions in DB1 and I know that many will be relevant to DB2?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Database Project using Visual Studio (I believe 2008 and 2010 support it). Keep object scripts organized within the project. Check the project and related files into some form of version control software (SVN, git, hg, SourceSafe...).

You should have a DBA or a dedicated person who is responsible for deploying code changes to your production environments. You can configure the database project with pre- and post-deployment scripts that can make this easier to work with.

I can't recommend keeping user-defined objects in `master`; IMHO you're better off with copies in each database. If you're managing your code as above it won't matter that they're duplicated, since the source is in a single, managed location.

Comment: I have only been using SQL server 'express' for a couple of months and have 2005 in production (as its the default contained in Windows SBS2008) and run SQL Server 2008 r2 Express on a laptop for development. Do you know whether your method will work within a Visual Express edition (sorry as I do not use Visual Studio, although I am thinking about downloading IronPython with the VisualStudio codebase project). Also, I will be the DBA. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I think you'll need at least the "professional" flavors of either VS 2008 or 2010. I may be wrong and you might want to check the MS web platform downloader since they change their offerings quite a bit. Even so, you can still organize your object scripts on a file system and keep them in version control. GForge is not a bad free SVN tool.